# Home/Up button not working with drawer navigation

Tags: android

I have an app that has one activity which uses a drawer layout and several fragments.

I want to it work like the Gmail app, where you have a drawer layout, a fragment to list all your mails and clicking on one mail opens another fragment which shows the full mail. On the mail fragment, there's a left caret on the action bar, that takes you to the list of mails.

The problem is, I am able to show the details fragment and change the hamburger icon to the up/home button, but pressing on that button opens/closes the navigation drawer.

I have the below code in my MainActivity class.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();   

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {                
            Log.i("PB", "PRESSED");
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

When I click on the Home/up button, it opens the drawer instead. The click isn't even intercepted by the `onOptionsItemSelected` listener, as I don't see the log message. So, am thinking it has something to do with the drawer layout. If I open a start activity without a drawer activity and put the same code above, it takes me to the previous screen as it should.

Comment: try this toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(this);

Comment: did you add the onoptioncreate in fragment or in activity ? If in fragment then did you add setHasOptionMenu(true); in fragment ?

Comment: @user2299040  This works! Now I can go back to the previous fragment. But another problem, when my app starts, it shows the hamburger icon, and if I click on it, it does not open the drawer, but closes the app (which is trying to go back).

Comment: @PreetikaKaur Yes, I have setHasOptionMenu(true) in my fragment.

Comment: @WebNovice put some logic in your click listener. you can open the drawer problematically. Think about it